# Determine $\frac{\partial f(x, y, z)}{\partial x}$ where $z$ is a function $z(x), z:\mathbb{R}_+\mapsto \mathbb{R}_+$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

How to I determine the partial derivative with respect to $x$ for a function $f(x,y,z)$ where $z$ is a function itself dependent on $x$?

I'm guessing I need to use the chain rule but I can't figure this out at all.

$x,y \in \mathbb{R}_+$.

Studying a few examples, I noticed the following:
Is it true that
$$
\frac{\partial f(x, y, z)}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f(x, y, z)}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f(x, y, z)}{\partial z}\frac{dz}{dx}
$$
?

Comment: Have you written out any concrete small examples?  This makes it pretty clear.

Comment: @Randall Examples for what, sorry? $z$ could be $z(x)=3x+5$, just a linear function if that's what you're looking for?

Comment: For instance, if $f(x,y,z) = 2x + 3y + 4z$ and $z=x^2$, finding $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ is pretty straightforward.  Note that $f$ is really just a function of two variables.  This would show you the general pattern.

Comment: Oh I see, no I don't have any examples unfortunately - I am to find the general solution. @Randall

Comment: Right.  But studying a few examples will show you how to formulate the general solution.

Comment: The notation $\partial f/\partial x$ is inadequate for expressing this.

Comment: @Randall Okay, I tried $2x+3y+4z$ and $5x6y7z$, which both lead to $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\frac{dz}{dx}$. I was using the product rule for the second equation. Is this correct? I still feel like I'm overcomplicating things. If this is correct, I'd still be looking for a neat explanation (possibly shorter or more elegant than my calculations) on why this is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is true.

if $z$ is a function of $x$ then $z=z(x)$, and let $w=f(x,y,z(x))$ then by applying the chain rule, we get
$$\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$$
since $y$ isn't a function of $x$, then its partial with respect to $x$ is $0$, and $z$ is a function of one variable, so we don't need the parial derivative, Hence   $$\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\frac{dz}{dx}$$

the other partial derivatives $\partial w/\partial y$ and $\partial w/\partial x$ are respectively $\partial f/\partial y$,   $\partial f/\partial x$ in other words they didn't change.

Comment: Hm, why do you add them up though? I mean I get that it is essentially the total derivative divided by $dx$ but the chain rule doesn't say anything about adding the terms together or does it?

Comment: Are you sure that you know the chain rule for multivariable functions ? read this 

https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calciii/chainrule.aspx.  @j3141592653589793238