# Let $z = f(y(x), x)$. Show that $\frac{dz}{dx} = \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} y + \frac{\partial z}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial x}$

Tags: calculus

Hello I am trying to show that $$\frac{dz}{dx} = \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} y + \frac{\partial z}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial x},$$ where $z = f(y(x), x)$.

As per my intuition, I went with the total derivative of $z$ with respect to $x$, but I get $$\frac{dz}{dx} = \frac{\partial z}{\delta x} + \frac{\partial z}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial x}.$$

Could someone please point out the concept I am missing that is causing no $y$ along with $\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ in the first term of $\dfrac{dz}{dx}$?

The derivative appears in https://www.cs.cornell.edu/home/kleinber/aer15-prediction.pdf

Comment: At first sight I would say that the statement is wrong and your derivation of correct.

Comment: The derivative appears in [link](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/home/kleinber/aer15-prediction.pdf)

Comment: Here is a close duplicate https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4143193/determine-frac-partial-fx-y-z-partial-x-where-z-is-a-function-zx/4143338#4143338

Comment: @user106742 In the linked paper, there are parentheses: $(Y)$. I think it does not mean a product, but an evaluation: after computing the partial derivative, you have to evaluate at $(X_0,Y)$ which requires prediction of $Y$, as discussed later in the paper.

Comment: There is also a slight ambiguity, wheter you consider $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ as the derivative with respect to the "variable" $x$ or with respect to the $x$-coordinate i.e. the first argument of the function. The confusion arises, when the $x$-coordinate input is named $y(x)$ and the input to the $y$-coordinate is $x$.

Answer (score 1):

In the linked paper, there are parentheses: $(Y)$. I think it does not mean a product, but an evaluation: after computing the partial derivative, you have to evaluate at $(X_0,Y)$ which requires prediction of $Y$, as discussed later in the paper.

Comment: Anyway notation is flawed and you were right to be confused. If they meant evaluation they should have included both variables $X_0,Y$ as in the definition of $\pi$.